# DRF Unable to have required=False Flag in Nested Model Serializer

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I m unable to sort this validation error.

My Address Model has a required field 'locality'.

```
class Address(models.Model):
      ....
      locality = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
      ....

class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ['house_number', 'street', 'area', 'locality', 'address_of']


class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ship_address = AddressSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
```

In Address model locality is a required field.

I want to have the AddressSerializer to be optional in CustomerSerializer. 
Inspite of having the required=False flag, I m getting a validation error :

```
"ship_address": {
        "locality": [
            "This field may not be blank."
        ]
    }
```

** Kindly note: This is just a representational one and not the exact replica of my models and serializers thus ignore any minor errors.

Comment: Did you already find a solution for this issue?

Comment: @XhensB No, I haven't. Wrote some custom validation for that particular serializer. If you have any, please let me know.

Comment: Yes, I found a solution. I added it as an answer. Give it a try, and if it works, accept the answer, please :)

Comment: @XhensB, That wont work for nested one.. Please check my requirement once again.

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ship_address = AddressSerializer(read_only=True)
```

and modify models.py 
`null=True` in field that you want to make optional

Comment: But that in AddressSerializer, location field is a must have.

To be clear with, I need the AddressSerializer to be optional(required=False), I m aware that required=False only for fields and not for serialisers. But, how to achieve that..?

Comment: make ship_address null=True in models.py and read_only = True will work here 100 %

Comment: If I make ship_address read_only, I cannot make those fields writable.

Once again, I m just reiterating. AddressSerializer has a must have field location. 

Now my point is in CustomerSerializer, AddressSerializer may or may not have data points - making it not a compulsive one.

Comment: nested write is not supported in DRF

https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/385

Comment: True Ravi, But I can override create method. That shouldn't be a problem here I think.

Comment: You can use create method in view function using request.data ... this  trick  work for me perfectly .

Answer (score 0):

You need some acrobatic. In your `viewsets` you determines the payload and the http-method. And use different `Serializer` class handle them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you with a nested serializer. In the end, I came up with a solution which was adding the `read_only` flag and it works like a charm. I hope this solves your issue.

```
class Meta:
    model = ModelName
    fields = ('pk', 'field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3')
    extra_kwargs = {
        'field_1': {
            'required': False,
            'read_only': True,
        },
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

DRF will make any field that has a constrain a required field, ignoring required=False *and not telling you your parameter is ignored*, see: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/discussions/7743 and more importantly in the official doc: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#optional-fields
In the case of the OP here, the unique=True constraint on locality is likely responsible for this.
It can be fixed adding a validators = [] in the serializer's Meta (then eventually checking for this elsewhere or let the database error out).

It's 2023 and I just wasted half a day on this.